# Help identify 1x2 modified plate with both pin and axle holes

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Trying to identify this piece to buy some extras. Can't find anything like it on Bricklink.

It came in a MOC set, not official Lego.

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image: 1x2 modified plate axle and pin holes]

Comment: I suspect a clone branded item. Does it have "LEGO" inside studs?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a clone brick. I guessed there must be a Lego equivalent but maybe not. Any idea if there's still a way to order the part on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEGO doesn't have any elements that have such geometry and offer connections for both pins and axles. The closest you can get from LEGO right now is [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18677#T=C)

[image]

And [Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32000#T=C) if you need to attach two pins/axles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex, that confirms what I've found too. The other is the 1 X 2 beam with axle and pin holes but no studs.

Comment: https://rebrickable.com/parts/60483/technic-beam-1-x-2-thick-with-pin-hole-and-axle-hole/